# Mulesoft: DataWeave convert date string to a datetime

Tags: datetime, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I need to convert a date string "23012021235129" to a date like "**2021-01-24T00:51:29.006+01:00**".

My code:

`|23012021235129| as LocalDateTime {format: "ddMMyyyyHHmmss"}) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+01:00"}`,

Result:

**"2021-01-23T23:51:29.000+01:00"**.

It's almost working except for the millisecond. Please advise what to do?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. `|23012021235129|` is be date time literal, not a string. Since the contents are not in valid format it fails. You need to replace the pipes by quotes to make it a string. And where the milliseconds in the expected output are supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

The input string ("23012021235129") has no milliseconds so it should be expected that in the output the number of milliseconds is zero.